# Basic mod_rewrite operation with question mark

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite an address from:

http://mysite.com/page?att=XXXXX
to:
http://mysite.com/page.php?att=XXXXX

I have tried the following code, but does not work for me. I guess the question mark is the problem:

```
RewriteRule ^page?att=([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ page.php?att=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would include an R directive to explicitly trigger a redirect, and QSA to simply preserve the entire query string in the redirect URL.

Finally, depending on the context, the URI may begin with a slash.  If so, your rule -- which requires the URI to *not* begin with a slash -- will never match.  Adding /? at the beginning will match both URIs with leading slash and without.

```
RewriteRule ^/?page/?$ page.php [R,QSA,L]
```

Give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can't match against the query string in a `RwriteRule`, but in this case, you're not rewriting the query string at all, you just need to rewrite the URI (`page` -> `page.php`) and the query string will automatically get appended:

```
RewriteRule ^/?page$ page.php [L]
```